# get checkbox values with angular4 module

Tags: angular

I am trying to update my data using angular4. but little bit stuck how to get all the selected values if i click on update button.

`

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let parts of info" class="text-center">
          <td>{{parts.modelD}}</td>
          <td>{{parts.start}}</td>
          <td>{{parts.end}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="editable_good_parts" id="editable_good_parts" value="{{parts.good_parts}}" style="max-width:100; text-align:center;"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="row_id" value="{{parts.id}}" [checked]="isSelected"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update Data</button>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let parts of info" class="text-center">
          <td>{{parts.modelD}}</td>
          <td>{{parts.start}}</td>
          <td>{{parts.end}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="editable_good_parts" id="editable_good_parts" value="{{parts.good_parts}}" style="max-width:100; text-align:center;"/></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="row_id" **[value]="parts.id"** [checked]="isSelected"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Update Data</button>
```

Just checkout with binded value attribute(Eg.  [value]="myData" )